# delphi - TRadioGroup with items wrapable

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, radio-group

I need a small example on Delphi 5 on how the text of the items present in a radiogroup to wrap text if needed.

I resolved it in Delphi 2006 by accessing buttons property, but in D5 this property does not exist.

LE: is there any solution except than SetWindowLong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

done.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: Integer;
 rbs: DWORD;
 rb: TRadioButton;
begin
 with RadioGroup1 do
 begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount-1 do
   begin
    rb := radiogroup1.controls[i] as TRadioButton;
    rbs := GetWindowLong(rb.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
    rbs := rbs or BS_MULTILINE or BS_TOP;
    SetWindowLong(rb.Handle, GWL_STYLE, rbs);
   end ;
   Invalidate;
 end ;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the buttons easily enough in Delphi 5 by iterating over the `Controls` property of the radio group. But then what are you going to do to make them wrap? The Delphi 5 radio button does not have a `WordWrap` property.

If I were you I would add a bunch of radio buttons to a group box rather than use a radio group. This gives you control over exactly what class of radio button you create. Then derive your own radio button class and implement the `WordWrap` property. To do this you need to add the `BS_MULTILINE` style in `CreateParams`, just as modern Delphi versions do.

Of course, the method outlined in your answer would work too!

Comment: By the way, I had not see your answer when I wrote mine. I was busy exploring my old Delphi versions!!

Comment: The indications on how to do it are very useful. I post the question, and after that wrote the code. anyway, you were extremely quick!